# What is the link between the density matrix and Hestenes' spinors in geometric algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, clifford-algebra

The density matrix (or state matrix) is a generalization of a wave function that is able to describe incoherent superpositions of an N-state system. It is often written as a matrix and observables are calculated by taking the trace of the product of itself with the operator in question.

Hestenes' spinors are a geometric algebra description of things like a wave function and Dirac 4-component spinor, but if one applies the matrix representation of the algebraic elements directly, it resembles a density matrix-like entity much more closely than a wave function, especially when looking at the mathematical expressions for observables. I know and understand the map from "normal" spinors to Hestenes' spinors, which kind of contradicts my proposition.

Nevertheless, a Hestenes spinor can be written as more general entities (a rotor and a scalar). Is this, in light of the above, a further "generalization" so to say? Or how do these objects relate?

Comment: Perhaps this paper helps? http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0004031 - it covers a lot more than your question but if you just search the document for "density" you should get your answer in various stages of generality.

Comment: Did you find out in the end? At first glance it seems using density matrices as the vectors in geometric algebra is more natural. And if "spinors are the square root of vectors", then why not work without square roots?